# Java - Making a card game, have questions about classes

Tags: java

I'm a (mostly) self taught programmer with one java class under my belt so I'm still very new to this and I'm trying to make my first real app from scratch.

Basically, I'm making an app version of a card game I own (just for me! Not to sell or anything!) and in this card game you basically use your starter cards to "buy" more cards from a lineup of cards drawn from the main deck. These cards have several values associated with them that would translate well to an app like "power level" and "point value," and in addition each of these cards does something special when you play it like "draw an extra card" or "destroy a card" or "give another player a negative card" - that type of thing.

I've already made the whole UI for the game, and have that (mostly) done, and now I'm working on the meat and potatoes of it all - the code. I've made a constructor class named Card that looks like this:

```
public class Card 
{
private int power;
private int value;
private String type;
private String cardName;
private ImageIcon image;

    public Card(int power, int value, String type, String cardName, ImageIcon image)
    {
        this.power = power;
        this.value = value;
        this.type = type;
        this.cardName = cardName;
        this.image = image;
    }
...
}
```

With the ellipses representing all my getter/setter methods.

So you can see that my Card class will assigns all the necessary values to them but one - the special "thing" that each of them do (draw card/destroy card..etc)

I'm not sure where/how I should put that in my code. Since the I have a type value that will represent the different types of cards you can draw (equipment/super power/hero/etc..) I'm thinking I should make a separate class for each card type..is this good coding practice?

So to conclude this extremely lengthy post, in summary - should I separate out all my different card "types" into different classes and how should I implement that special "thing" that each card does? I feel like it will be wrapped in a method, but as far as I know, I can't have a method be a part of a constructor, can I?

Comment: So you are implementing a deck-building game, huh?

Comment: Haha yes sir. It's the DC deck building game, I'm in love with it and thought that the rules seemed so rigid and perfect for a digital version as my first real project.

Comment: [This one?](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/125678/dc-comics-deck-building-game)

Comment: That's the one! My wife and I play it quite a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the Card either an **interface** or an **abstract class**. If you go with the latter, you can actually define logic sort of like what you already have above. Depending on the route you go, each "Card" would either implement the interface or extend the abstract class.

The downside to the interface is that you have to re-implement all the fields as private variables for the sub-class.

**Abstract**

```
public abstract class Card  {
    protected int power;
    protected int value;
    protected String type;
    protected String cardName;
    protected ImageIcon image;

    // You cannot instantiate this directly, only through children.
    public Card(int power, int value, String type, String cardName, ImageIcon image) {
        this.power = power;
        this.value = value;
        this.type = type;
        this.cardName = cardName;
        this.image = image;
    }

    // Getters/Setters...
}

public class AttackCard extends Card {
    public AttackCard(int power, int value, String type, String cardName, ImageIcon image);
        super(power, value, type, cardName, image);
    }
}
```

**Interface**

```
public interface Card  {
    int getPower();
    int getValue();
    String getType();
    String getCardName();
    ImageIcon getImage();
}

public class AttackCard implements Card {
    private int power;
    private int value;
    private String type;
    private String cardName;
    private ImageIcon image;

    public AttackCard(int power, int value, String type, String cardName, ImageIcon image);
        this.power = power;
        this.value = value;
        this.type = type;
        this.cardName = cardName;
        this.image = image;
    }

    // Implement methods from Card...
}
```

---

**Edit**

If you are implementing the DC Comics deck-building game then you may only need to have 1 abstract class for all cards and an interface for Hero, Villain, Super Power, and Starter. Not sure what all they types are... Then all the Heroes would extend the abstract card class for all the common properties of cards and implement the methods that are Hero-specific.

You would not need a separate class for each card. Each hero would just be an instance of Hero. You would just have a Collection of Hero cards.

```
// Hierarchy
abstract class Card
interface Hero
interface Villain
class HeroCard extends Card implements Hero
class VillainCard extends Card implements Villain

// Example constructors definitions for reference?
Card(String name, int value, int power);
HeroCard(String name, int value, int power);
VillainCard(String name, int value, int power);

// Create all heroes
List<Hero> heroes = new ArrayList<Hero>();
heroes.add(new HeroCard("Green Arrow", 5, 2));

// Create all villains
List<Villain> villains = new ArrayList<Villains>();
villains.add(new VillainCard("Ra's Al Ghul", 8, 3));

// All all the heroes and villains to all cards
List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
cards.addAll(heroes);
card.addAll(villains);
```

Comment: If I made card an Interface, I could still keep all my private variables and constructors right? And if so, can I make each different card implement the Card interface's method for the "special thing" individually within the same class, or would I have to make a new class for each and every card?

Comment: Oops, I updated my answer. The implementation would have to re-implement all variables, because interfaces can only have public methods and fields, and the methods cannot be blocks. The abstract class provides all the fields across children as long as they are **protected**.

Comment: I like the way the interface version looks, but what I was asking before is if I do it that way, wouldn't I have to create a separate class for each card? The only reason I'm concerned about that is the sheer quantity of different cards (around 64 different cards!)

Comment: Well, if you have 64 different cards, and they all have almost 90% common attributes, then go with the abstract class. If they only share less than half common functionality, then you may need to use an interface.

Comment: So since every single card will share the power, value, type, cardName, and image property it would make sense to go with abstract. The thing I'm really struggling with is if I need to make a separate class that extends the abstract Card class for all 64 different cards? I don't mind doing the work, it just seems like there would be a simpler solution in there somewhere.

Comment: It would make it easier on me in explaining things if I ask, are you familiar with this game personally? Have you played it before?

Comment: No, but I have played Dominion and I have checked it out on BordgameGeek. I added a class hierarchy as en example in my answer above.

Comment: Awesome. Glad I found a fellow card gamer for help! So going by your edit, where would I put my method for their individual functionality? The part I keep calling their "special thing"...lol. I think it needs to be connected to the card before it's added to the collection - which by the way was my plan for after I figured this part out, to make a collection that they get added to.

Comment: Like for example the Hero card Dark Knight, he gives +2 power but also does "Gain all equipment in the lineup, if you play catwoman, add the card to the top of your deck." I don't need to know how to implement that specifically, just how I attach that function to his Card

Comment: Well, the special attribute can be tricky... you may need to post another question dealing with how to handle special events for each card. [***You should check this out***](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/28074/how-to-implement-the-logic-of-a-trading-card-games-special-effects-cards). You will have to implement global triggers and rules which all cards can perform which will effect the environment of the game like having other players discard and re-shuffling your deck, etc.. etc..

Comment: Awesome, you've been a massive help and I really appreciate it. For now, I'm going to implement your suggestion and what I'll do is just add some buttons on the UI to allow players to basically click and do the function of the card without it being automated. I think automating things like that might be a bit more advanced than I'm capable of right now - but I can always add that functionality later!

Comment: Glad to hear it. I believe that programming board/card-games can be fun and rewarding.

Comment: Last question, I promise! What's the difference between creating Interfaces for each type of card (heroes/villains/etc..) and adding them to a specific type array, then to the main card array- and just just doing the same thing but cut out the interface and just add each card to the main Card array, since they all just get shuffled into the same deck anyway?

Comment: Well, that was an example of how I can add all the `Hero`/`Villain`s to their respective interface then add all the implementations to the cards list. You could have just as easily added the `HeroCard`s and `VillainCard`s right into the `Card` list.

Comment: Awesome, that's what I thought. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `inheritance` where a general class will be there the `functionality` common for all `Card` classes you can put there and after that in each subclasses `Card` you can put specific functionality of the class and also can use common functionality of the base class.Also you can override the methods of the superclass.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

```
 public class SuperCardClass {
 ........

  public void someCommonFunction() {

  }

 }

 public class SubCardFirstClass extends SuperCardClass {

  @Override
   public void someCommonFunction() {
     //specific to sub class
   }

 }
```

Comment: Inheritance makes sense for the different "types" but at the same time, I would need to implement some sort of method for each and every card for the special thing they do. Each card (it's based on DC heroes) has a unique thing that only it can do and I need to implement that thing somehow and attach it to the constructed card.

Comment: @lfernandes You can put that functionality in base class and can override that functionality in each sub classes